# Conditional Insert

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to fill a temporary table on happening of certain condition,
if a select statement return some result than that statement, else another statement will fill table
e.g;

> if exists(select name from table where
>   name='zain') insert into #table(name) 
>   --values from above select statement
>
> else if exists(select name from table
>   where name='ali')

`insert into  #table(name)            --values from above select statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
INSERT INTO #table (name)
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='zain'

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #table (name)
        SELECT name FROM table WHERE name='ali'
    END
```